# Simulink: Selected signal originates from an unconnected source

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a bit of an annoyance rather than a major problem, that I would like to tackle. I have a subsystem that creates a bus inside it and outputs it via a Scope. The bus creation is through From tags, that depend on signals from *other* components.

Now, when I don't have those components, I get a warning saying something like:

```
Warning: Selected signal 'Compressor' in 'untitled/Pressure/Bus Selector' 
originates from an unconnected source signal 
entering 'untitled/Output Data/Bus Creator12' at input port 1
```

It seems there is no way to turn this off in the Diagnostics pane (Connectivity sub-pane or otherwise). It seems it was a bug in *very* old versions of Matlab, but was fixed in R13, according to these links:

[Link 1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95469-why-do-i-receive-warnings-about-unconnected-source-signals-when-all-signals-are-connected-in-my-simm),

[Link 2 (search for "unconnected source signal" on the page)](http://www-afs.secure-endpoints.com/afs/CSAIL/system/ppc_darwin_70/matlab/MATLAB701/help/bugfixes_13SP1.html)

I'm using 2013a, a full 12 years later. Anyone have more information on how I can turn this warning off?

Comment: Would connecting a ground signal to the unconnected components do the job?

Comment: Unfortunately, while I could do that for _my_ model and it would work, I'm trying to find a solution that works without intervention. I need to basically give my component library to an end user who shouldn't have to make modifications to signals.

Comment: Leaving signals unconnected is not a recommended practice as far as I am concerned, so I would not be surprised if it were not possible. Besides, grounding an unconnected input signal is not a modification in my opinion... Just my two cents. Good luck!

Comment: Is there a straightforward command that can be used to check if it is unconnected? I've used linehandles in the past to determine when lines are unconnected, but what would be the equivalent for Bus signals? Or checking the origins of From tags?